# Can an enemy fall asleep in your arms?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain, metal-gear-solid-3-snake-eater, metal-gear-solid-peace-walker

When you shoot an ennemy with the *Wu Silent Pistol* or the *Mk-22*, he falls asleep after a short time (except for headshots).

#### What happens if you shoot an enemy, and grab him *before* he passes out ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can only answer for Peace Walker, but if you tranq a enemy before CQC holding him, he can fall asleep on you, you'll automatically let him go.

Comment: That's what I suspected, but I couldn't test, since I don't own any of those games. Thank you !

Comment: Confirm this happens in Phantom Pain as well. Luckily I'd already asked him the pertinent question.

Answer (score 4):

In MGS 5, this can happen with Quiet as buddy.

If you're grabbing an enemy right before Quiet shoots him, Snake will let that enemy go. This has happened to me with both lethal and non-lethal Quiet, so whether they sleep or die, Snake will let go of them in any case.

Comment: I remember dragging sleeping guards in MGS 3, but I don't remember the game that well, so I might be mistaken.

Comment: In MGS 3 and 5, you can drag/carry sleeping guards.

Answer (score 0):

In MGSV, if you've shot an enemy with a tranquilizer weapon in the arm, leg, or torso, and you then grab them to interrogate them before the tranquilizer takes effect, they will often fall asleep while you are holding them, and collapse to the ground. This has happened to me a number of times, and it seems like they're more likely to fall asleep IMMEDIATELY after you grab them. If you want, I can capture a video via PS4 share the next time it happens to me.